# How to posting to WordPress using C#?

Tags: c#, api, wordpress, posting

I want to write a program that can post data into WordPress using C# via POST method. I have no idea to do that. I hope someone help me some ideas. WordPress have any API support that ?

Thanks !

Comment: Most Blog systems allow you to submit posts to them using XMLRPC. Most use variants of the Blogger, metaWebLog or similar APIs. [Wordpress does, too](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support).

Comment: You may use [WordPress’ XML-RPC interface](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support). There are many good libraries from which you can choose ([example](http://xml-rpc.net/)).

Comment: Joeblogs wordpress wrapper helps a lot with this (I just happen to manage this project)
http://joeblogs.codeplex.com/ **UPDATE** Moved project to GitHub: http://github.com/alexjamesbrown/JoeBlogs