# How to create wordpress posts from c#?

Tags: c#, wordpress, post

I want to create posts automatically in wordpress with c# and each post should have an image or two uploaded automatically.
Which is the easiest method?

Comment: Please read [faq] and [ask], please..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to posting to WordPress using C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2584106/how-to-posting-to-wordpress-using-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you have two options:

1. Manipulate the Wordpress database via C#
2. Using a Service in the Wordpress site to allow the manipulation via RESTful API. For this you can use this wordpress plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/json-api/other_notes/